# Unknown Path components on Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to write a program which would post using Graph API. This is my program:

```
def publish_image():
    access_token = input("Enter token:")
    ig_user_id = "123456789"
    image_url = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-X7ebk4LF4wM/WhAwtetCWYI/AAAAAAAAABs/Z_ADLy9CayMYjp2IXmytVV_0-FnN4R3QgCEwYBhgL/s640/xiaomiredminote5awithmiui9unveiledsaledebutstoday3-22-1503368214.jpg"

    post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v.17/{}/media".format(ig_user_id)
    payload = {
        'image_url':image_url,
        'caption': 'Instagram Post using Graph API',
        access_token:access_token
    }

    r=requests.post(post_url,data=payload)
    print(r.text)

publish_image()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/123456789\/media","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"xxxxxxxxx"}}
```

Comment: Were you able to find the rootcause? I am also facing the same problem. I am trying to upload video using https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{upload-session-id}